# Authenticate users in MVC5 using a method called from WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a WCF service which performs actions over a database and also has a method ValidateUser. I also have an asp-net mvc 5 app that does not have access to the database. I want to authorize my ASP.NET MVC users using this `Validate()` method in WCF service. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an ActionFilter (IAuthorizationFilter) in your application. This will ensure application wide authorization.

To accomplish this, you'll need to add a Service Reference to your WCF Service, and authorize the user inside your ActionFilter. You will also consider caching the result into your sessions to prevent having to authorize on each call (as this will adversely impact performance).

You can find an overview of ActionFilters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)